# What database table is used by WordPress for extra post info, such as labels, genres, categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't often work with WordPress. I am being asked to fix a problem on a WordPress site. "Genres" and "tags" and "labels" are not appearing in the final HTML, even though they are supposed to.

version 4.4.1

When I log into admin, I see that I can create a post, and in the right hand sidebar, there is a place where I can add extra data to the post.

Each of these have a block on the right where I can add them: "tags", "labels", "genres", "categories", "placements".

I want to find out where in the database this data is kept. If I do:

```
  show tables;
```

I get:

```
  +--------------------------------+
  | Tables_in_thelineup_production |
  +--------------------------------+
  | wp_amd_zlrecipe_recipes        |
  | wp_apto_sort_list              |
  | wp_commentmeta                 |
  | wp_comments                    |
  | wp_itro_plugin_field           |
  | wp_itro_plugin_option          |
  | wp_links                       |
  | wp_options                     |
  | wp_popularpostsdata            |
  | wp_popularpostssummary         |
  | wp_postmeta                    |
  | wp_posts                       |
  | wp_term_relationships          |
  | wp_term_taxonomy               |
  | wp_termmeta                    |
  | wp_terms                       |
  | wp_usermeta                    |
  | wp_users                       |
  | wp_w3tc_cdn_queue              |
  | wp_wp_rp_tags                  |
  +--------------------------------+
```

I looked through most of these and could not find anything about "labels" or "genres" or "tags".

Where is this data kept?

UPDATE:

In functions.php I see this blocks registered like this:

```
   register_taxonomy('display_category', array_merge(array('post'),     array('marketing'), $post_types), array(
   'label' => 'Label',
   'labels' => array(
   'name'              => _x( 'Labels', 'taxonomy general name' ),
   'singular_name'     => _x( 'Label', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
   'search_items'      => __( 'Search Labels' ),
   'all_items'         => __( 'All Labels' ),
   'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Label' ),
   'update_item'       => __( 'Update Label' ),
   'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Label' ),
   'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Label' ),
   'menu_name'         => __( 'Label' ),
   'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from most used labels'),
   'not_found' => __('No labels found')
 ) ,
 'query_var' => 'label',
 'hierarchical' => true
 ));
```

but I don't see where they are stored in the database.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `postmeta` table.

Comment: If I do "select distinct meta_key from  wp_postmeta   ;" I don't see anything that looks like a genre or a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are stored in `wp_terms` with a `term_group` of 0.

The others are possibly stored there too.  Genres and some of the others might also be theme specific.

I would check `wp_terms` first, then `wp_postmeta` and possible `wp_options`.

Or dig into the theme files (possibly functions.php but it could be elsewhere) and see if it has any hooks to `save_post` that might process some of those values to see where they're going.